# Как создать модуль для laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Раньше работал с yii2, теперь переключился на ларавел, мне нужно сгенерить модуль где будет лежать функционал. Нужно что-бы была возможность конфигурировать этот модуль указывать параметры. Как это сделать вобще не понимаю.

Answer (score -1):

Создание модели artisa командой:

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -m
```

Ключ -m указывает что будет создана миграция

Создание контроллера artisa командой:

```
php artisan make:controller MyController
```

Comment: Я не понимаю, вы что тролите ? )  Я же описал сверху модуль